# How do I select lists inside a list that have a specific length in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, if-statement, functional-programming

In Haskell I have a list that looks like this:

```
[[["PersonA"],["AddressA"]],[["PersonB"],["AddressB"]],[["PersonC"]]]
```

and I need the lists within my list that have length=2, i.e. the people that I know the address of. In this case, I would want:

```
[["PersonA"],["Address"]]

and

[["PersonB"],["Address"]]
```

and I would not want PersonC because I don't have his address.

I was thinking about something like:

```
myList = [[["PersonA"],["123456789"]],[["PersonC"],["987654321"]],[["PersonE"]]]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  map (\x -> if length x == 2 print x else print "") myList
```

(print is just an example, I will need to work with them later)

But this returns a

> Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘[IO ()]’

error on line 5.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Ick. Use a real type, like `data Person = Person { name :: String, address :: Maybe String }`.

Comment: How would you use that? Also since I want to discard the data people without an address, wouldn't it store useless information? And I will still need to check who has the address and who doesn't when I need it further in my program.

Comment: BourbonCreams, @DanielWagner is likely suggesting that you avoid ever getting into the situation where you're representing a person as a list like that. It's only going to cause you pain.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `print` is an `IO` action, and to sequence these you'd need to use [`mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM_) instead of `map` to also get back the `IO ()` that `main` expects. Alternatively, wrap the list of `IO` actions that `map` produced in a [`sequence_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence_) call.

But I don't think this is the right approach anyway. To select from a list, you should use [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:filter) not `map`:

```
myList = [[["PersonA"],["123456789"]],[["PersonC"],["987654321"]],[["PersonE"]]]
myLen2List = filter (\x -> length x == 2) myList

main :: IO ()
main = print myLen2List
```

---

That said, @Daniel Wagner is totally right in the comments. Don't use lists as your custom data type.

```
data Person = Person { name :: String, address :: Maybe String } deriving (Eq, Show)
myList = [ Person "PersonA" (Just "123456789"),
           Person "PersonC" (Just "987654321"),
           Person "PersonE" Nothing ]

myAddressList = filter (isJust . address) myList

main = print myAddressList
```

Comment: You're right, I should have thought about filter in the first place. Thanks for that.

(mapM_ makes it work too)

Comment: Better still, I think, would be to have a `personWithAddress` type as well, and produce a list of those using `mapMaybe`.